# How do calculators work with precision?

Tags: floating-point, precision, calculator

I wonder how calculators work with precision. For example the value of `sin(M_PI)` is not exactly zero when computed in `double` precision:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double x = sin(M_PI);
    printf("%.20f\n", x); // 0.00000000000000012246
    return 0;
}
```

Now I would certainly want to print zero when user enters sin(π). I can easily round somewhere on 1e–15 to make this particular case work, but that’s a hack, not a solution. When I start to round like this and the user enters something like 1e–20, they get a zero back (because of the rounding). The same thing happens when the user enters 1/10 and hits the <kbd>=</kbd> key repeatedly — when he reaches the rounding treshold, he gets zero.

And yet some calculators return plain zero for sin(π) and at the same time they can work with expressions such as (1e–20)/10 comfortably. Where’s the trick?

Comment: Which calculators are you talking about?

Comment: For example the calculator that ships with iPods and iPhones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Desktop Calculators use arbitrary precision math libraries. Those can be configured to have much higher precision that double.  Handheld calculators (tradition dedicated and mobile phones) use fixed precision math libraries.

If you want to print exactly zero, use width specifier

```
printf (%12.4d, number);
```

Comment: Depends on the calculator. For instance, Mathematica calculates in arbitrary precision (as stated by its documentation e.g. the Numeric Precision tutorial). I'm sure there are other calculators that do the same, as well as some that use high-precision (but not arbitrary precision) libraries and perhaps some that just do regular floating-point math.

Comment: @Mark: Well, the question is asking about software calculators, and Mathematica is just a generalization of the same concept. Regardless of how you define "calculator," though, it's likely that different ones will use different precisions.

Comment: @High Performance Mark: Default calculator on ubuntu uses arbitrary precision math library thus I chose to generalize the idea.

Answer (score 4):

Some answers can be found on this [Calculator Precision](http://www.thimet.de/CalcCollection/Calc-Precision.html) page.

Among solutions are:

- work in BCD
- use lookup tables
- use hidden digits, so that displayed digits are accurate

Comment: BCD is not really more accurate than binary; the advantage is that it mimics pencil-and-paper calculations, and therefore you get the exact same accuracy or inaccuracy.

Comment: With binary, there is one source of inaccurracy more than BCD: this is the conversion of the result from base-2 to base-10.

Comment: The relative precision indicated by a decimal number that's shown with e.g. six significant figures may vary from about one part per million (if the mantissa is 9.99999) to ten parts per million (if 1.00000), a nearly-tenfold variation.  The relative precision of binary floating point numbers only varies by a factor of two.  Thus, for the binary representation to be as accurate as the decimal in all cases, it must be ten (if not twenty) times as accurate in some cases.  Using BCD doesn't really help, though; to ensure a certain level of relative precision in all intermediate calculations...

Comment: ...will in many cases end up requiring an "extra" digit; even then, the large variance in precision can often cause problems of its own.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is probably, as already said, that calculators will use [arbitrary precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) math libraries or [lookup tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table).

I'd also add that your code snippet works that way due to using [floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) arithmetics, which as you probably know is not *true* math in the sense it's not precise - `1.0 + 0.1 != 1.1` (it's actually 1.1000000000000001) :)

Answer (score 2):

They may be using a lookup table to speed up their trig formulas.  In that case the special numbers that work out nicely would probably just be in the table.