# Why are calculators accurate with decimal?

Tags: binary

We know that computers cannot store some decimals accurately, such as .1, .2, .3, .4, .6, etc.  But, if a calculator works on just bits how are they accurate?  I just used a solar powered $1 calculator to add .1 ten times and got 1.0 exactly.  If computers cannot store those decimals precisely, how are calculators being accurate?  The only thing I can think of is that they are using objects instead of just basic bits, but I'm doubting that is the case.

Comment: Your question is very good. Here is somewhat similar one. Non of the answers made sense to me though! If you got a good answer please share it. https://www.quora.com/If-computers-cannot-compute-floating-numbers-accurately-how-do-calculators-and-scientific-computers-function

Comment: This may provide better answers than the above link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713649/how-do-calculators-work-with-precision